# How to play CS 1.5 online?

Tags: counter-strike

What do you have to do to play **Counter-Strike 1.5** online?

Valve discontinued [WON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Opponent_Network). Fans created [WON2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WON2).

Is using WON2 the only way to play CS 1.5 online? Do you get a list of public servers (or how else do you find servers to play on)?

(FWIW, there seems to be a way to [play 1.5 on Steam](http://www.no-won.net/steam.html), but I don't want to use Steam.)

Answer (score 3):

An option you can use is connecting to the server directly.

But to do it you will have to know the IP address and the port of the server. When you know it, just start the game, open console(if you don't have the `console` button, enable it by adding `-console` in the shortcut after `hl.exe`(or whatever it is named)) and type:

```
connect <IP address of the server>:<port(27015 per default iIrc)>
```

Hope it helps.